# Converting a natural number to a permutation matrix in Python. How to speed it up perhaps avoiding messing around with lists, sets and dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, base64

It is something a bit complex to explain here, but the  code bellow takes a 128-bit number and converts it into a [permutation matrix, a beast which I have already faced before](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/241511/how-to-efficiently-fast-calculate-the-transpose-of-a-permutation-matrix-in-p). The matrix is represented as a list of numbers. Each number is a row. 
The way I've found to do the mapping number->matrix was to convert the number through a [multi-radix (or something that could be considered one)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3652556/is-there-any-stablished-concept-of-a-numeric-base-that-increases-linearly-the-al)  numeric system, so each digit corresponds to a row in the matrix. Since there can't be duplicate rows, some offset magic was needed (that is one of the uses of map `taboo` used below).
How could this code be improved regarding data structures and use of loops?
More conceptually, what about my choice of conversion through a multi-radix system?
Could it be simpler and still be a perfect mapping from naturals to permutation matrices?

ps. There are 2^128 numbers and 35! matrices.  `2^128 < 35!` , So all numbers can have a unique corresponding matrix.

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet, SortedDict
def permutmatrix2int(m):
    """Convert permutation matrix 35x35 to number."""
    taboo = SortedSet()
    digits = []
    rowid = 34
    for bit in m[:-1]:
        bitold = bit
        for f in taboo:
            if bitold >= f:
                bit -= 1
        taboo.add(bitold)
        digits.append(bit)
        rowid -= 1

    big_number = digits[0]
    pos = 0
    base = b = 35
    for digit in digits[1:]:
        big_number += b * digit
        pos += 1
        base -= 1
        b *= base

    return big_number


def int2permutmatrix(big_number):
    """Convert number to permutation matrix 35x35."""
    taboo = SortedDict()
    res = big_number
    base = 35
    bit = 0
    while base > 1:
        res, bit = divmod(res, base)
        if res + bit == 0:
            bit = 0
        for ta in taboo:
            if bit >= ta:
                bit += 1
        base -= 1
        taboo[bit] = base

    for bit in range(35):
        if bit not in taboo:
            break
    taboo[bit] = base - 1

    return list(map(
        itemgetter(0), sorted(taboo.items(), reverse=True, key=itemgetter(1))
    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a great help from a [mathematician (at least in spirit)](https://www.quora.com/profile/Mark-Gritter) regarding permutations, factoradic and matrices, I could implement the following, which is 30 times faster.

I provide the opposite function as a bonus.

```
def pmatrix2int(m):
    """Convert permutation matrix to number."""
    return fac2int(pmatrix2fac(m))


def int2pmatrix(big_number):
    """Convert number to permutation matrix."""
    return fac2pmatrix((int2fac(big_number)))


def pmatrix2fac(matrix):
    """Convert permutation matrix to factoradic number."""
    available = list(range(len(matrix)))
    digits = []
    for row in matrix:
        idx = available.index(row)
        del available[idx]
        digits.append(idx)
    return list(reversed(digits))


def fac2pmatrix(digits):
    """Convert factoradic number to permutation matrix."""
    available = list(range(len(digits)))
    mat = []
    for digit in reversed(digits):
        # print(digit, available)
        mat.append(available.pop(digit))
    return mat


def int2fac(number):
    """Convert decimal into factorial numeric system. Left-most is LSB."""
    i = 2
    res = [0]
    while number > 0:
        number, r = divmod(number, i)
        res.append(r)
        i += 1
    return res


def fac2int(digits):
    """Convert factorial numeric system into decimal. Left-most is LSB."""
    radix = 1
    i = 1
    res = 0
    for digit in digits[1:]:
        res += digit * i
        radix += 1
        i *= radix
    return res
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't really tried to follow your code, but it sounds like you're complicating things unnecessarily by talking about "permutation matrices" instead of just "permutations." IIUC, it's trivial to get from a permutation matrix to a permutation or vice versa. The hard part is getting from an integer index ("give me the 42nd permutation of these elements") to the actual permutation.

So, the non-trivial functions you're looking for are

```
def nth_permutation(num_elements, which):
    [...]

def index_of_permutation(num_elements, which):
    [...]
```

The speedy algorithm for `nth_permutation` is described [here (with C and PHP code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918806/finding-n-th-permutation-without-computing-others)
and [here in Python, although apparently the first version doesn't produce permutations in the traditional order and the second version is quadratic](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/126037-getting-nth-permutation-of-a-sequence/).

---

On your actual code, I'm confused by this passage:

```
    res, bit = divmod(res, base)
    if res + bit == 0:
        bit = 0
```

How can `res + bit == 0`, unless `(res == 0) and (bit == 0)`? But if `(bit == 0)`, then it's redundant to assign `bit = 0`.

---

I also don't understand the significance of `35`. Is it significant that there are 10+26-1 non-zero "digits" available in base 36? If `35` was picked completely at random, then you should really make it a *parameter* to the function. It'd be what I called `num_elements` in my signatures above.

---

Trivial nit: you forgot

```
from operator import itemgetter
```

---

```
big_number = digits[0]
pos = 0
base = b = 35
for digit in digits[1:]:
    big_number += b * digit
    pos += 1
    base -= 1
    b *= base
```

This looks suspiciously like "convert string to int." Is this essentially equivalent to

```
alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY"
big_string = ''.join([alphabet[i] for i in digits])
big_number = int(big_string[::-1]], 35)
```

?